# Text doesn't wrap inside text box

Tags: html, css, text

Text doesn't wrap, instead it infinitely goes to the right. How to I make it so it breaks when it can no longer fit on its line, and start writing on a new line underneath.

CSS

```
  #eventDescriptionInput {
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 25px;
border-radius: 3px;
outline: none;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px gray;
padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="eventDescriptionInput" placeholder="Description" />
```

Comment: Try using `<textarea>` instead of `<input>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your purpose:

```
<textarea id="eventDescriptionInput" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
```